# Dynamically including Reactjs components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have a dashboard with areas for widgets. Position 1 can contain a clock, a weather widget or a choice of 10 or 12 other widgets. same for position 2, 3, 4 etc.

In Vue I would use  to dynamically include a widget. The benifit of this is that I can then only update a specific widget.

My issue in React is that Im finding myself so something like this in a master widget container

```
if (currentWidget === 'clock') {
 return (<Clock settings='clockSettings' />)
}
if (currentWidget === 'weather') {
 return (<Weather settings='weatherSettings' />)
}
```

I have a componentDidUpdate passing the currentWidget name. Now if the props for the clockSettings update I get a repaint of all the widgets which is a big issue.

is there a react way of doing this or something similar to Vues

Comment: Well, you can write a static array for each component and its related info, and use it as a switch

Comment: The problem is that I have 65 widgets yet to make and I want to find a more succinct way

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you need to update in react components, store that variable in local state if you are using class components like this.state = { variable_name: ""}.

If you are using functional components, same thing store in local state using hooks.
e.g: const [currentWidget, setCurrentWidget] = useState("").

Comment: Thats not what Im asking though. I know how to do all that. The problem is if there are 2 widgets present and i change the settings for one of them they both are updating